# Wordpress category archive page showing Notice : Undefined offset: error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am now at this url:

http://myproject.test/category/learn/

now, I want to show the first 4 posts with the same design but the last post of this 4 posts will be that post which meta key is equal to sponsored_post and meta value is eqaul to 1

and then remaining posts will be another design.

**So in cateogry.php page I have this code:**

```
<?php  
if( have_posts() ) {
    $counter = 1;
    echo '<div class="row">';
        while( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            if( $counter <= 3 ) {
                echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                    get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'category-box-post');
                echo '</div>';
            } elseif( $counter == 4 ) {
                echo '<div class="col-md-6">';                                        
                   get_template_part( 'template-parts/category-archive-sponsored-post' );
                echo '</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
                    get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'category-horizental-post');
                echo '</div>';
            }                            
            $counter++;
        }
    echo '</div>';              
} else {
    _e( 'No post found!', 'everstrap' );
}
?>
```

Now, you can see this line:

```
 get_template_part( 'template-parts/category-archive-sponsored-post' );
```

It's counting number 4 and on this 4th number post I want to show meta key / value post;

**So category-archive-sponsored-post.php code is**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(
                $queried_object->slug
            )
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'sponsored_post',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if( $posts ) {
     foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
         setup_postdata( $post );
         the_title();
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

But I got an error message look like this:

```
Notice
: Undefined offset: 4 in
C:\laragon\www\my-project\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php
on line
3275
```

I think something is wrong on the 4th post query? Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error occurs? you could drop some debug output to see how far code gets.  Also is this correct? spelling/ typo? category-horizental-post or category-horizontal-post

Comment: It's category-horizental-post

Comment: and on that category-archive-sponsored-post.php page, I put some demo code. It's doesn't show any error?